# Tail-recursion and scalaz promises

Tags: scala, tail-recursion, scalaz, promise

I am currently playing with Scalaz non-blocking futures aka. Promises. I am struggling to make the following function tail-recursive:

```
@tailrec
private def repeat( res: Promise[I] ):Promise[I] =
  res map p flatMap { 
    (b:Boolean) =>
      if( b ) repeat( res flatMap f ) else res
  }
```

where `p` is a predicate with type `I=>Boolean` and `f` is a concurrent function with
type `I=>Promise[I]`.

The method compiles without the annotation.

Any hints ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method isn't recursive at all. `res` is a computation potentially running in another thread. `res map p flatMap f` will immediately return a promise as far as your method is concerned. The recurrence to `repeat` will occur in a different process.

In slightly more terse terms, `Promise` is a continuation monad, and `flatMap` calls are automatically translated to continuation-passing style for you.

Answer (score 1):

Although this looks tail recursive because the call appears only once in code, you have more than one recursive call - one for each element inside your collection. At least that's what the compiler sees. (Supposing this is a flatMap on some collection; I have no idea what `p` does return)

You pass the recursion to somewhere as an anonymous function. No one knows how often it will be executed.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But have you an idea about how I can solve to that without blocking ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with scalaz. I just tried to find out what the `p` call in your code is and failed. Can you think of a procedural version of your code that uses a while loop? If this isn't possible there can't be a tco.

Comment: "one for each element inside your collection. At least that's what the compiler sees." is incorrect, IMHO: `Promise` isn't a collection and the compiler does only see one call (not in a tail position). However, the second paragraph is both correct and sufficient to explain why this isn't tail recursive.